# Displaying only the title on the client returns undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I have a defined a schema in mongoosejs like this:

```
var uploadSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title            : String,
    happy            : String,
});
```

I want the data in my db to be displayed on the client (I am using ejs for templating):

```
app.get('/yay', function (req, res, next){
        Upload.find({}, function (err, course){
            res.render('./pages/yay.ejs', {course: course});
        });
    });
```

Displaying it on the client:

```
<div class="well">
    <p><%= course %></p>
</div>
```

But this just displays the whole db with the id, whatWillLearn. I only need to display the title. How can I do this? I have tried this:

```
app.get('/yay', function (req, res, next){
            Upload.find({}, function (err, course){
                res.render('./pages/yay.ejs', {course: course.title});
            });
        });
```

But it just returns undefined on the client. What should I do?

Comment: Simply said, you can't access _individual fields_ of a document from Mangoose ? But the _whole document_ is displayed without any issue ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Does `<p><%= happy.title %></p>` work?

Comment: No it does not. It returns undefined.

Comment: Could you *copy-paste* a sample of your data ? Maybe for example what was displayed when you tried `res.render('./pages/yay.ejs', {happy: course})`...

Comment: Where is `course` defined?

Also `Upload.find` will return an array, not a find DB element. So happy would be an array. So to access an element you would need to either loop or use the index.
ex: `happy[0].title` or if course is your result then `course[0].title`

Comment: Could you post the complete code @etre.matthew?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are returning an array, but the correct variable is not being set in the object passed to render

Give this a try (this should get the 1st course in the array):

```
app.get('/yay', function (req, res, next){
  Upload.find({}, function (err, courses) {
    res.render('./pages/yay.ejs', { happy: courses[0].title });
  });
});
```

If you have no courses this will not work. You should probably loop through all the courses that you return and print them out, or change change Upload.find to Upload.findOne to just get 1 back from the DB

Comment: Thanks this worked. I have another question though. What would happen if I change Upload.find to findOne. Also, how would I get all the courses in the array.

Comment: If you change to `Upload.findOne` you will not need to do `courses[0].title` you can change it to `courses.title` because Upload.findOne returns a single element from the DB instead of an array.

To print everything you would need to update you template to loop through the result
`<div class="well">
   <% for(var i=0; i<courses.length; i++) { %>
      <p><%= courses[i].title %></p>
    <% } %>
</div>`

Comment: Its giving me undefined again.